# Search the ip address of my server

Tags: bash

I want to connect the workstation after its power off. The ip address is changed. However I don't want to connect the monitor and type `ifconfig` command. I know the ip address is 192.168.1.XXX. How can I write a loop to search the ip address?

I often use `ssh myname@192.168.1.XXX` to login to the workstation.

Here is my work around(failed although), in the terminal I type:

```
for i in {1..255}
do 
   ssh myname @192.168.1.$i
done
```

The return results is:

```
ssh: connect to host prefix.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host prefix.2 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host prefix.3 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host prefix.4 port 22: No route to host
ssh: connect to host prefix.5 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host prefix.6 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host prefix.7 port 22: No route to host
ssh: connect to host prefix.8 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host prefix.9 port 22: No route to host
```

Everytime when return `No route to host`, it will hang a long time to try the next number. How can I make it quick? **Question is how to skip the wrong ip quickly. Can I use a timeout option in ssh command?**

Another problem is that when I reach an ip that is open for ssh login(ask me to enter the password), but it is not my workstation. I have to `ctrl-c` to kill this loop and then start from this position again. How can I do it automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is already in the question, i.e. to set a timeout, like this:

```
for i in {1..255}
do 
   ssh -o ConnectTimeout=1 myname @192.168.1.$i
done
```

You need only about 4min to go over all the numbers. If anyone know how to set time less than 1, it will be quicker.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your workstation's mac address, install `arp-scan` (or just do port scan with `nmap` (already on one of the answer)), and do `grep` with the mac address. Then connect with `ssh`.

This is easier than having to loop over unknown ip addresses on your LAN.

More on `arp-scan` : https://superuser.com/questions/236476/find-an-ip-address-by-mac-address-on-lan

Answer (score 0):

You're on a right path, but it's going to be hard to have all the pros and no cons.

You can attempt login until one succeeds, and stop then:

```
for i in {1..255}; do
   ssh myname@192.168.1.$i && break
done
```

Pros: don't keep trying once a connection has been made. 
Cons: takes a long time to reach the end of the list. Supposes you end your session with no error, else it keeps trying to the end. (could be mitigated)

You could try and parallelize the connections:

```
for i in {1..255}; do 
   ssh myname@192.168.1.$i &
done
```

If your setup is lucky enough, all but one will fail with no I/O, and you can foreground the one that succeeds.

Pros: faster 
Cons: untested, more tricky to set up (needs interactive shell with job control)

Comment: Not work. Please note I need to enter the password manually when I come across an ip address that support ssh login.

Comment: for example, using my code, when reaching number 33, I have to enter my password. But that is not my workstation's ip. So I must ctrl-c to end it.

Comment: How do you expect a hypothetical automation script to guess whether or not it's your workstation at the other end? You can't ask for magic.

Comment: If automatically let the computer enter the password for me is not possible. How about let the connection time reduce to a certain amount of time. for example when trying an ip address, let it at most spend 1 sec to try. After all, when I have the right ip address, it will connect much less than one sec.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `nmap 192.168.1.0/24 -p 22 --host-timeout 5ms`

This will scan your network and show all the devices with port 22 open. Your workstation will be among them.

If you have access to DHCP server (e.g. your wifi router) then you can see which IP addresses were served recently.

Comment: You can use it, but what for? Some elaboration would be helpful. :)

Comment: Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-09-14 15:45 CST
You cannot use -F (fast scan) or -p (explicit port selection) when not doing a port scan
QUITTING!

Comment: After removing the -p 22, I got first three 1,2,3. which is not right

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the command right? You don't need -sP flags now. Do these first three devices also have port 22 open? How do you distinguish them from your workstation then?

Comment: sure, your code return different results every time i try. some time one or two ips returned. sometimes a dozens of ips returned.

Comment: no kidding, after I removed -sP, here is some results of different runnings:
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (52 hosts up) scanned in 13.14 seconds
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (24 hosts up) scanned in 0.15 seconds
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (33 hosts up) scanned in 0.15 seconds

Comment: increase host-timeout for more stable results